# Game Theory: draw sets using a program?

Tags: matrices, game-theory

I am asked to draw two different sets, S1 and S2 using a program to determine if the sets are equal. But for starters, I don't know how am I supposed to "draw" a set with a program and I have never heard a thing like that. Do you know any good resources to understand more about the topic?

The problem I am talking about:

> Given a bimatrix $(A, B)$ we can define two sets:
> $S_{1},$ the set of all outcomes that can be reached when the players coordinate their strategies and $S_{2}$, the set of outcomes that can be reached when the players cannot coordinate their strategies. (It is the set $S_{1}$ we use in Nash's bargain solution.) If we take the bimatrix
>
> $$
> \left(\begin{array}{ll}
> (2,1) & (1,0) \\
> (0,1) & (1,2)
> \end{array}\right)
> $$
>
> Then $S_{1}=\{\alpha(2,1)+\beta(1,0)+\gamma(0,1)+\delta(1,2)\}$ where $0 \leq \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \leq 1$, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta=1$.
>
> The set $S_{2}$ is
>
> $$
> \left\{\left(\bar{x}\left(\begin{array}{ll}
> 2 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1
> \end{array}\right) \bar{y}^{T}, \bar{x}\left(\begin{array}{ll}
> 1 & 0 \\
> 1 & 2
> \end{array}\right) \bar{y}^{T}\right)\right\}
> $$
>
> where $\bar{x}, \bar{y}$ are probability vectors. Draw both sets (you can use any program or tool). Are the sets equal?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question.

Comment: Next time, for easier mathjax (latex) you can use tools like [mathquill](http://mathquill.com) and [mathpix](https://mathpix.com).

Answer (score 0):

Both sets are subsets of $\ \mathbb{R}^2\ $.  I would take the  instruction to "draw" these sets as asking you to construct diagrams to represent them, just as you do when you draw the graph of a function.  If I were to ask you to draw the set
$$
S_3=\left\{x_1(0,0)+x_2(0,1)+x_3(1,0)\,\bigg|\,0\le x_i, \sum_{i=1}^3x_i=1\right\}\ ,
$$
for instance, I would expect you to produce a diagram something like the one below, not necessarily done with
a graphing app like [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/), which I used.  A similar hand-drawn diagram should be perfectly acceptable.

[image]